# How to not double count values in a map c++

Tags: c++, maps

I have a map and I want to count the number of unique values held for each key. I.e for the key '3' I want to have the printout say that there is one Events with one Photon Pt, rather than 2, i.e I want repeated values for each key to only count once. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void test4() {
    std::map<int, std::vector<double>> map { // Data to look through.
      {1, {3098.0, 3097.5, 3099.0, 3094.0, 3094.0, 3094.0}},
      {2, {3098.0, 3093.0, 3095.0, 3094.0, 3095.0}},
      {3, {3098.0, 3098.0}}
      };


   std::vector <Double_t>  Photon_Pt_greater_than_one_less_than_two;
   std::vector <Double_t>  Photon_Pt_greater_than_two_less_than_three;
   std::vector <Double_t> Photon_Pt_greater_than_two;

   std::map <Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> >::iterator Iter2 = map.begin();
   std::map <Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> >::iterator Iter2_End = map.end();



   for ( ; Iter2 != Iter2_End ; Iter2++){

     Int_t EvtNum = Iter2->first;
     std::vector<Double_t> Photon_Pt = Iter2->second;




      if(Iter2->second.size()==1){
        Photon_Pt_greater_than_one_less_than_two.push_back(Iter2->first);
          };

      if (Iter2->second.size()==2){
     Photon_Pt_greater_than_two_less_than_three.push_back(Iter2->first);
      };

      if (Iter2->second.size()>2){
     Photon_Pt_greater_than_two.push_back(Iter2->first);
      };

  };

   std::cout << Photon_Pt_greater_than_one_less_than_two.size() << "     Events with one Photon Pt" << std::endl;
  std::cout <<  Photon_Pt_greater_than_two_less_than_three.size() << " Events with two Photon_pts" << std::endl;
  std::cout << Photon_Pt_greater_than_two.size() << " Events with more than two Photon_Pts" << std::endl;
```

}

This has now been solved. See solution below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

void test4() {
    std::map<int, std::vector<double>> map { // Data to look through.
      {1, {3098.0, 3097.5, 3099.0, 3094.0, 3094.0, 3094.0}},  //one event with 4 photon pts so an event with more than 2 photon pTs.
      {2, {3098.0, 3093.0, 3095.0, 3094.0, 3095.0}}, //This should count as 1 event with 4 photon pTs so an event with more than 2 photon pTs
      {3, {3098.0, 3098.0}},  //this should count as one event with one photon pt
      {4, {3098.0, 3099.0}}
      };


   std::vector <Double_t>  Photon_Pt_greater_than_one_less_than_two;
   std::vector <Double_t>  Photon_Pt_greater_than_two_less_than_three;
   std::vector <Double_t> Photon_Pt_greater_than_two;

   std::map <Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> >::iterator Iter2 = map.begin();
   std::map <Int_t, std::vector<Double_t> >::iterator Iter2_End = map.end();



   for ( ; Iter2 != Iter2_End ; Iter2++){

     Int_t EvtNum = Iter2->first;
     std::vector<Double_t> Photon_Pt = Iter2->second;

     std::sort (Iter2->second.begin(), Iter2->second.end());
     auto last =  std::unique (Iter2->second.begin(), Iter2->second.end());

     Iter2->second.erase(last, Iter2->second.end());

      if(Iter2->second.size()==1){
       Photon_Pt_greater_than_one_less_than_two.push_back(Iter2->first)
        };

      if (Iter2->second.size()==2){
     Photon_Pt_greater_than_two_less_than_three.push_back(Iter2->first);
      };

     if (Iter2->second.size()>2){
    Photon_Pt_greater_than_two.push_back(Iter2->first);
      }

   };

      std::cout << Photon_Pt_greater_than_one_less_than_two.size() << " Events with one Photon Pt" << std::endl;
  std::cout <<  Photon_Pt_greater_than_two_less_than_three.size() << " Events with two Photon_pts" << std::endl;
  std::cout << Photon_Pt_greater_than_two.size() << " Events with more than two Photon_Pts" << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: You can use `std::unique`

Comment: Thanks I appear to have solved the problem using std::unique

Comment: can you post your solution?

Comment: I will edit my original post.